# How to have a % in a python statement without using two %

Tags: python

so my python application opens a link that would be found in my config file. I would like to make it so it would like to allow it to go to the website without doubling the %. Heres what I would want `config.get('CONFIG', 'Website')` the web address has a bunch of %'s in the link but when I run it, the process ends

Comment: What exactly to you mean by "run it"? A `%` in a string is only an issue if you use it with the `%` operator.

Comment: Please add more details. %d is digit. You can use something like `int(your_number)` to make it integer

Comment: Your TypeError is pointing on the problem. You are using formated strings. So instead of giving a ```%d``` a number you give a ```str```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the `configparser` module?

If so, you can use [`ConfigParser(interpolation=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser) to disable string interpolation (which controls the behavior of `%` characters in the config file).

(Or on older versions of Python, you may need to use [`RawConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html#rawconfigparser-objects) instead.)

Comment: thanks a bunch it works now